# How can I do certificate pinning for TLS sockets in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I have a python TLS server using a self signed certificate.  That works.  The code looks like this for now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket, ssl

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="server.crt", keyfile="server.key")

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
bindsocket.listen(5)

while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)
    try:
        print("Got connection!")
    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
```

I am now trying to make a client in python that connects to this server.  On the first connection attempt, I'd like to retrieve either the public key, or a hash of the public key, and then verify this on all future connections.  How can I do with with python and the ssl package?

This is the code I'm playing with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ssl, socket, pprint

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = False


cnx = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET), certfile="server.crt")
cnx.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
pprint.pprint(cnx.getpeercert())
```

As it stands right now, it fails because there is no certificate chain to verify the cert.  I don't care about that, though.  All I care about is that the server I'm talking to has the private key that matches the public key.  What do I do?

Comment: When the client connects to the server it gets the server certificate, which is its public key with some metadata. So you have to hardcode the public key you want in the client and test that it matches what the server sent you.

Comment: So set context.verify_mode to ssl.CERT_NONE?  How do I then retrieve the public key?

Comment: Did you try instead to use the certificate itself as the CA file so that the validation is still done and is by design restricted to only one given certificate? Of course if you need to take into account more than one autosigned then you can not do that.

Comment: I was hoping to do this without having to store the entire cert locally as a file.  There ought to be able to be a way to just connect and check the public key.  However, I've made this approach work and it may be good enough for my purposes.  Thank you.

Comment: With `ssl` it does not seem possible as is (you could always shell out to the `openssl` command but that would be ugly) but with `PyOpenSSL`, when you have a certificate you can use `get_pubkey()` on it to retrieve the public key. I would still advise to keep the certificate validation, storing it locally seems a small constraint, otherwise you may miss many security problems.

Comment: Just checking the public key is not enough. Imagine a fake server configured to send you an invalid certificate with the specific public key you want (which is easy to know as your true server broadcasts it to any connecting client) and another locally made private key. The certificate signature would not match obviously but you do not check it at all. You will believe the public key part and go forward with TLS. Of course as long as you stay completely on `127.0.0.1` and without unsecured accounts, you are kind of safe, but still not validating certificates is not a good idea at all.

Comment: But I'm going to be encrypting using that public key.  So to pull off that attack, they'd have to generate another key pair with the same public key, but a different private key.  Is that easy?

Comment: Note also that TLS allows you to use shared keys, instead of certificates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK. This seems better suited to your use case, than messing with certificates. Of course the keys need to be secured.

Comment: See the "Certificate pinning" part under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Dealing_with_man-in-the-middle_attacks : *"certificate pinning", sometimes called "SSL pinning", but more accurately called "public key pinning"* AND *A client that does key pinning adds an extra step beyond the normal X.509 certificate validation: After obtaining the server's certificate in the standard way,*.  Pinning (either key or cert) is an additional step AFTER certificate validation, not instead of it.

Comment: *But I'm going to be encrypting using that public key.* By definition of it being public, anyone grabing it will be able to send you trafic encrypted with it. As you do not validate the certificate you did not validate that the server has in fact the corresponding private key. See "Basic TLS Handshake" under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake.  This changed with TLS 1.3, there is no ClientKeyExchange nor PreMasterSecret anymore.

Comment: "they'd have to generate another key pair with the same public key, but a different private key." that is of course "impossible" otherwise any HTTPS website will be easily spoofed. My attack is different: the server would send an invalid certificate composed of a private key it generated (any one) and your specific public key. The certificate signature will be invalid as the private and public keys do not relate in any way, but if you do not check the certificate at all, this mismatch will not be seen. After that the TLS handshake will be successful.

Comment: But the client will encrypt the pre-master key with the server's public key, and then send it to the server.  The server won't be able to decrypt it, because it won't know the private key.  So the server won't be able to create the same session key that the client is using.

Comment: The ClientKeyExchange does not necessarily uses the PreMasterSecret, it can uses other keys in case of not doing RSA authentication (see 7.4.7 of TLS 1.2 RFC), then it is Diffie-Hellman. So it all depends on the cipher suites negotiated between both parties. Note also that ClientKeyExchange and PreMasterSecret disappeared in TLS 1.3. In short I still think that disabling certificate validation will expose you to too many dangers. Instead use TLS-PSK if you dislike certificates, that will be cleaner.

Comment: This is exactly addressing your use case: https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=8446#appendix-C.5    This (in TLS 1.3 specification) summaizes our discussion here in some way. Should have found that sooner :-)

Comment: And, interestingly the attack described above is exactly what is explained here https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-barnes-dane-uks-00 which also gives countermeasures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've made this work, though it's not exactly what I hoped for.  My biggest complaint is that it requires storing the entire server certificate in a file on disk, whereas really all I care about is the public key.  However, here's what I have working:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ssl, socket, pprint, os, sys

# If we haven't retrieved the certificate previously...
if not os.path.isfile('server_cert.pem'):

    # Grab the cert
    cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('127.0.0.1', 8888))

    # If it worked...
    if cert:

        # Write it to a file
        with open('server_cert.pem', 'w') as f:
            f.write(cert)
    else:
        sys.exit()

# Prepare context, including reference to the server's certificate
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = False
context.load_verify_locations(cafile='server_cert.pem')
cnx = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET))

# Connect and evaluate
cnx.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
```

I'll wait a bit to mark this answer accepted to see if someone can find a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: If you dislike having it as a file on the disk, you can always store it as a string in your code and use `cadata` in `load_verify_locaions()` instead of `cafile`. Of course, you will then need to maintain it...

Comment: That's not certificate pinning, it's *trust on first use*. There's a difference.

Comment: Is the difference in the method the key is distributed (meaning, it's certificate pinning if it's distributed through some other, secure channel, rather than provided on first use by the device)?

Comment: TOFU (Trust On First Use) is used for example by `ssh`: when you connect first time to an host it shows you the key (or whatever derived from it) as retrieved from host and asks you if you recognize it and want to go further (as it does not have locally in any way). If yes, it stores the key and then check it at each future new connection. This is basically what your code above does. It works... with the caveat that if at the first connection the exchange is compromised in any way and/or the user does not take care then all future exchanges are compromised without detection.